# Complex linq ranking with group sum and take

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5, rank

I have sports application that scores competitors on their 3 best results. A tie breaker that is a count of the number of "first time" completions of their results. The code below takes their 3 best results, sums the value of those results, and counts the number of first time results. The output is grouped by gender and category (age group).

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> Prelims()
    {
        IQueryable<CompResults>
            compdata = from result in db.Result
                       where result.Complete == true
                       group result by new
                       {
                           result.CompetitorId,
                           result.Competitor.FirstName,
                           result.Competitor.LastName,
                           result.Competitor.Category,
                           result.Competitor.Gender,
                       } into resultsGroup

                       select new CompResults()
                       {
                           CompetitorId = resultsGroup.Key.CompetitorId,
                           Name = resultsGroup.Key.FirstName + " " + resultsGroup.Key.LastName,
                           Category = resultsGroup.Key.Category,
                           Gender = resultsGroup.Key.Gender,
                           PrelimsScore = resultsGroup.OrderByDescending(s => s.Event.Value).Take(3).Sum(s => s.Event.Value),
                           TotalFirstTime = resultsGroup.OrderByDescending(s => s.Event.Value).Take(3).Where(s => s.FirstTime == true).Count(),
                       };

        return View(await compdata.OrderBy(c => c.Category).ThenBy(c => c.Gender).ThenByDescending(c => c.PrelimsScore).ThenByDescending(c => c.TotalFirstTime).ToListAsync());
    }
```

I would like to add a ranking over category and gender. Can I modify my existing code or start with a new approach? I am hopelessly confused right now.

Comment: So your code is working and now you are looking to Order `compdata` By `Category` ThenBy `Gender`?

Comment: No I already have the ordering in place. I would like to add ranking by category and gender.

Comment: Can you add a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and add a demon on [.NETFiddle](http://dotnetfiddle.net/)?

Comment: I gave up and decided to use raw SQL instead. Thanks for trying.